# How to mock objects of a Python class?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

Lets say I the following class;

```
class CompositionClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._redis = Redis()
        self._binance_client = BinanceClient()

    def do_processing(self, data):
        self._redis.write(data)
        self._binance_client.buy(data.amount_to_buy)

        # logic to actually unittest

        return process_val
```

I have other objects which call external API as composition in my `ComplexClass`. When I am unittesting the logic of `do_processing`, I do not want to call these expensive API calls. I have checked throughly in SO and Google about unittesting; all examples are simple not that really useful. In my case how can I use `unittest.mock` to mock these objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of mocking the `Redis` and `BinanceClient` classes is to use the `patch` decorator in your test class, such as:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from package.module import CompositionClass

class TestCompositionClass(TestCase):

    @patch('package.module.BinanceClient')
    @patch('package.module.Redis')
    def test_do_processing(self, mock_redis, mock_binance):
        c = CompositionClass()
        data = [...]
        c.do_processing(data)

        # Perform your assertions

        # Check that mocks were called
        mock_redis.return_value.write.assert_called_once_with(data)
        mock_binance.return_value.buy.assert_called_once_with(data.amount_to_buy)
```

Note that the path specified to `@patch` is the path to module containing the `CompositionClass` and its imports for `Redis` and `BinanceClient`. The patching happens in that module, not the module containing the `Redis` and `BinanceClient` implementations themselves.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Worked as expected :)

Comment: The thing I was missing was `mock_something.return_value.<method>`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a value that must be returned by your API call, to this function:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_do_processing(self):

        self.API_function = MagicMock(return_value='API_response')
        # test logic
```

Comment: How will this work? How will unittest.mock know to mock the particular function? Because we haven't specified it? Is `self.API_function = self._redis`?

Comment: It can be any function `self._redis.wait = MagicMock(...)` or `self._binance_client.buy = MagicMock(..)` or any other. You just set a value that replaced real call to the function.

Comment: Sorry it does not work; it says `Tester object has no attribute _redis.wait`

Comment: replace `API_function` to your function name

Comment: yes I did it does not work. I have updated my comment